# Installing GitHub for WIndows to non C:\ drive

Tags: windows-installer

Due to a smallish SSD C:\, I'd like to install [GitHub Desktop for Windows](https://desktop.github.com/) to my D: or F: drive.

GitHub supports says:

> The ClickOnce installer we use only installs on a per-user basis to %LocalAppData%. Currently we don't have an alternate installation method available.

Is there someway to change %LocalAppData% for the install? I guess I'd have to change it each time I run the app too.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make a symbolic link for the git hub directory using the mklink command.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

If github uses c:\users**user**\AppData\Local\GitHub then copy everything  in c:\users**user**\AppData\Local\GitHub to e:\github

then at the command prompt

mklink /d c:\users**user**\AppData\Local\GitHub e:\github

Anything written or read from c:\users**user**\AppData\Local\GitHub will now actually be reading and writing from e:\github.

This should work, but I haven't used the command much myself.